# What is the variable type of an object variable?

Tags: java, variables

When we create an object for instance variables in java, is that created variable also a instance variable since it is made for instance variables?
eg: `Demo demo= new Demo();`
I need to know about "demo"

Comment: The object is instance itself,  whereas the object variable is the reference variable - "demo" [link for tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 2):

Consider this statement in Java

```
int i = 0;
```

Here `i` is a variable of the type `int`. Similarly when we say

```
Demo demo= new Demo();
```

`demo` is a variable of the type `Demo`, which contains a reference to an object of class Demo.

By an instance variable, we mean they are variables belonging to a particular instance (of a class) and an Object is simply an instance of a class.

I liked this particular explanation about Classes in a StackOverflow Answer:

If you like housing metaphors:

- a class is like the blueprint for a house. Using this blueprint, you can build as many houses as you like.
- each house you build (or instantiate, in OO lingo) is an object, also known as an instance.
- each house also has an address, of course. If you want to tell someone where the house is, you give them a card with the address written on it. That card is the object's reference.
- If you want to visit the house, you look at the address written on the card. This is called dereferencing

Comment: I am asking is it a method local variable? because it only exist inside a the method scope. or instance variable for what reason I don't know?

Comment: Yes, if the object is declared within a method, you can term it as a local variable as it exists only inside the method scope. But you cannot term it as an instance variable as Instance variables are those that are declared in a class, but outside a method, constructor or any block.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest you study a good tutorial on Java. but just to give you an idea here goes the answer.

Demo demo= new Demo(); the demo variable you create is actually a reference variable. it does not hold the actual value of the object but refers to the object in the memory heap. its hold a address to the actual object created in the memory. just like a pointer.